# Copying directories and files while deploying

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, directory, qt-creator

I have some files in a directory that are not included in my project because I don't know at compile time how many if any exist but if they do exist, they will be used by the application.

When I hit the build button, those are obviously not copied into the deployment directory, how could I include a directory and all its content systematically when I build ?

Comment: This question is vague and could use clarification: why are you uncertain what files will be available at build time? What types of files are these? header files, source files? What build system are you using? make?

Comment: Those are data files, they are created at runtime or added manually by the user and read by the application when needed. I am using qMake.

Comment: OK, you have, or expect to have data files in a directory, say `/tmp/data` for now. During the build process you would like files in /tmp/data to be copied to (let's say) `/deployment/data`?

Comment: I have 3 subdirs projects, one of them is a static library that is shared with the other 2, so in the library project, i manually added a "Data" directory which will be populated by files at distribution (pre generated files by me) and more will follow by the user, those files are used by the application to display content to the user.  What i am trying to figure out is do i have to manually copy those in the debug and then eventually in the release directories or is there a way to link them during "build".